# String conversion from numeric to string in awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have below `awk` command which give mentioned result as well.

```
echo '1600000.00000000' '1600000.0000' | awk '{ print ($1 != $2) ? "true" : "false" }'
```

Result is : - **false**

As per numeric value the result given by the command is correct.
But I want command must consider both input(`'1600000.00000000'` `'1600000.0000'`) as `string` and give the result as `true`. Because If you consider both input as `string` then they are not equal difference is there in precision.

Answer (score 8):

From the GNU Awk user's guide, to force a number to be converted to a string, concatenate that number with the empty string `""`

```
$ echo '1600000.00000000' '1600000.0000' |
  awk '{ print ($1"" != $2"") ? "true" : "false" }'
```

Comment: Thank you very much etopylight....Its worked for me. Thanks to stackoverflow team as well.

Comment: I think concatenating one of them is enough... `($1"" != $2)`

Comment: @Sundeep That worked too :) didn't noticed that a string comparison can be forced if at least an operand is a string type

Comment: @AmolMurkute Cool, glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `sprintf`:

```
echo '1600000.00000000' '1600000.0000' |\
awk '{ print(sprintf("%f",$1) == sprintf("%f",$2)) ? "true": "false"}'
true
```